# Link a field either to ID on one table or to ID on another

Tags: ms-access, relationship

In MS-Access, I've got a table where its key input is either a primary key of one type (of companies) or the primary key of another type (of companies). There's virtually no overlap in fields between these two types (hence they're separate tables).

How does one structure this as links etc just relate to one table?
Thank you

Comment: Post sample data and explain better what is the problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Use a *union* query. The official guide is here:

[Use a union query to combine multiple queries into a single result](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-union-query-to-combine-multiple-queries-into-a-single-result-1F772EC0-CC73-474D-AB10-AD0A75541C6E)